# How was the mobile version of Saints Row 2 Sold/Distributed?

Tags: saints-row-2

In addition to console and PC releases, a version of Saints Row 2 was also released for devices running the J2ME platform - but I can't find any information on how this particular version was sold/distributed. Would anybody be able to offer some insight on this?